# list of structures, to be sorted or searched (C++)

Tags: c++, list, search, stl, structure

I have a list of structures(structure having parameters as name and number(both of string type)).
I need to search the list for all the matches for a given string(name or number) input by user.
I tried to use the std::search but i am not able to do that.
Is there a way i can do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking an "How do I" code question, you should try and post sample code demonstrating the problem you are having and what you have tried, ideally in the form of a [small, self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/). See the [How To Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) FAQ for more help.

Comment: Use `std::find` not `std::search`.

Comment: I ll in future for sure. kfsone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood, you have a struct A and an object list of A, so:

```
struct A {
  string name;
  int num;
}

class B {
  public:
    list<A>::iterator findName(const string& n) {
      list<A>::iterator it = listOfA.begin();
      for(; it != listOfA.end(); ++it) {
         if((*it).name == n) {
           return it;
         }
      }
      return 0; 
    }
    list<A>::iterator findNum(const int& n) {
      list<A>::iterator it = listOfA.begin();
      for(; it != listOfA.end(); ++it) {
         if((*it).num == n) {
           return it;
         }
      }
      return 0; 
    } 
  private:
    list<A> listOfA;
 }
```

For the **sorting** of your list there are a lot of methods; for instance you can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/).